# Select cols from a list of list of data frames (with differing names)

Tags: r

I have a list of lists of data frames that contain a lot of genetic variant information.
Now I would like to extract some cols from these DFs. A problem is that the names of the cols differ in some DFs.
Is there a recommended way to solve this issue?

```
# example data
df1 <- data.frame(Gene = 1:10, Consequence1= 11:20, other_stuff = 21:30)
df2 <- data.frame(Gene = 1:10, Consequence= 11:20, other_stuff = 21:30)
df3 <- data.frame(Gene = 1:10, Consequence= 11:20, other_stuff = 21:30)

family1 <- list(cpht = df1, hm = df2, ht = df3)
family2 <- list(cpht = df1, hm = df2, ht = df3)

gene_lists <- list(family1 = family1, family2 = family2)
```

The cols I would like to extract are named: 'Gene' and either 'Consequence1' or 'Consequence'.
A viable option would be to rename the col named 'Consequence1' into 'Consequence' but even this didn't work out so far.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your final result but one approach would be to use `lapply` to loop over the lists and e.g. `grepl` to extract the desired columns:

```r
# example data
df1 <- data.frame(Gene = 1:10, Consequence1= 11:20, other_stuff = 21:30)
df2 <- data.frame(Gene = 1:10, Consequence= 11:20, other_stuff = 21:30)
df3 <- data.frame(Gene = 1:10, Consequence= 11:20, other_stuff = 21:30)

family1 <- list(cpht = df1, hm = df2, ht = df3)
family2 <- list(cpht = df1, hm = df2, ht = df3)

gene_lists <- list(family1 = family1, family2 = family2)

gene_columns <- lapply(gene_lists, function(x) lapply(x, function(x) x[, names(x)[grepl("^(Gene|Consequence)", names(x))]]))

gene_columns$family1$ht
#>    Gene Consequence
#> 1     1          11
#> 2     2          12
#> 3     3          13
#> 4     4          14
#> 5     5          15
#> 6     6          16
#> 7     7          17
#> 8     8          18
#> 9     9          19
#> 10   10          20
```

**EDIT** To rename the column `Consequence1` and only select `Consequence` you could do:

```r
gene_columns <- lapply(gene_lists, function(x) lapply(x, function(x) { 
  names(x)[grepl("^Consequence1$", names(x))] <- "Consequence"  
  x[, c("Gene", "Consequence")]
  }
))
```

Comment: Could you maybe also help me with renaming the col named "Consequence1' into 'Consequence' and deleting the "Consequence2" col?

Comment: Hi Sebastian. I just added an edit. That should do the job. It first renames `Consequence1` to `Consequence` and afterwards selects `Gene` and `Consequence`. Just in case: There is always a column named `Consequence1` or `Consequence` in your dfs?

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your edit!

No, the cols are either Cons1 and Cons2 (in case of compound heterozygous variants) OR Cons only (for mom/heterozygous variants).